# PopOverController custom size and sourceRect does not work

Tags: swift

Added a bar button and when bar button is clicked then would like to display the tableview. There are two issues in my implementation.

First, I could not able to achieve popovercontroller `sourceRect` with my `BarButtonItem`

Second, `TableView` is being displayed full screen, not a custom size that I defined.

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.refresh, target: self, action: #selector(displayClassRooms(_:)))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button



@objc private func displayClassRooms(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let popController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ClassRoomVC")
    popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect.init(x: 300, y: 0, width: 50, height: 180 )
    popController.preferredContentSize = CGSize.init(width: 200, height: 200)
    present(popController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` to your controller class.

Set the popController delegate.

```
    let popoverContentController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ClassRoomVC")
    popoverContentController?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    
    if let popoverPresentationController = popoverContentController?.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .up
        popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
        popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect.init(x: 300, y: 0, width: 50, height: 180 )
        popoverPresentationController.delegate = self
        if let popoverController = popoverContentController {
            present(popoverController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have already added `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` to my class, but same issue.

Comment: same issue which I reported in the question, still popover is displayed in the full screen.

Comment: i tried it my side and works good but here i take a button and pop controller from button frame as source rect try this way and let me know it's work or not?

Comment: Would you mind to push your example to github and share the url, please?

Comment: yeah sure wait.

Comment: https://github.com/jatinfl15/PopController/blob/main/SOViewController.swift check this

Comment: I exactly copied and pasted your solution but still no luck! Would you mind to share the xcode project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232025/discussion-between-rbs-and-konya).

Comment: never mind, it is working now! thank you so much!